# R. Creating a function to change vectors

Tags: r, function, vector

I need to create a function that will take a numerical vector as an input (ex (-2, -4, 0, 5, 10)) and will

1. change all 0 into 'NA' and
2. change other values into 1/x (ex 2->1/2).

I've managed to do the first part, yet I can't figure out how to do the second (tried obvious solutions like 1/y, where y is a vector, but it doesn't work, due to NAs, I assume).

Can anyone help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: a simple if/else statement may suffice. could you show how you achieved the first part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward solution is `ifelse` as in

```
ivansfun <- function(x) ifelse(x == 0, yes = NA, no = 1/x)
```

which works like this

```
> ivansfun( c(-2, -4, 0, 5, 10) )
[1] -0.50 -0.25    NA  0.20  0.10
```

There is one important caveat: usually you should avoid using `==` with floating point variables as in `x == 0`. That's a complicated but important matter that is worth reading more then one stackoverflow answer. Start here and then use a search engine for equal floating-point numbers: https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

A better algorithm may be to just compute `1/0` which is an error in most languages but not in R. In R this will give `Inf` which you can either leave as is or replace `Inf`s by `NA` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
foo <- function(x){
  1/dplyr::na_if(x, 0)
}

foo(c(-2, -4, 0, 5, 10))
[1] -0.50 -0.25    NA  0.20  0.10
```

or

```
na_if(1/c(-2, -4, 0, 5, 10), Inf)
```